# Link Namespace window throwing an error

Tags: namespace, dev-hub, 2gp

When I click the "Link Namespace" button, it pops up a new window and then give this error:

[image]

Is the only way to resolve by contacting support?

Comment: Does your packaging org have Login IP Ranges configured?

Comment: It did. I just removed them all (both network access and profile) and tried again, got the same result

Comment: I had a similar problem for newly created dev orgs. This problem gone the next day. so contact support, or wait some time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like Oleksandr Berehovskyi was right. Was just a timing issue. It worked now.